# How to expose methods from the preload script of the main window to child windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In my Game Launcher Electron project I was trying to open a subwindow with a button click, and in there, offer additional features. These features include for example: opening exe files.

For this I need Node.js, so I've tried to create methods for this in the preload script and expose them via contextBridge.

These methods work fine in the main BrowserWindow. However, they are not reachable from the subwindow (Uncaught ReferenceError: game is not defined). See the code below:

preload.js

```js
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'game', {
        open: () => {
            console.log('test');
        },
        openAddGamePage: () => {
            console.log('test');
        }
    }
);
```

renderer.js (script for main window), the exposed methods work fine here.

```js
document.getElementById('openAddGameWindow').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const childWindow = window.open('features/addGame/addGamePage.html', '_blank', 'nodeIntegration=yes')
    game.open()
    game.openAddGamePage()
})
```

addGame.js (script from addGamePage.html): The methods don't work here

```js
document.getElementById('addGameButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
    game.open()
})
```

I also tried to include the functions directly in the "addGame.js" and enable nodeIntegration when creating the child window, however this did not work either (require is not defined).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you are opening your “subwindow” from the render process. IE: From your `renderer.js` file.

Doing so does not automatically give you access to the previous windows `preload.js` script. Actually, it is quite the opposite.

To have access to the `preload.js` script from your “subwindow”, the window must be opened by Electron from the main process, just like your main window.

The best way to achieve this would be, upon a button click, send an IPC message from your render process to your main process. When the message is received by your main process, it will open your “subwindow” using the same `preload.js` script, thus giving you access to the same functions as your main window.

Below is a minimum reproducible example. Check for the `test` text in the Developer Tools - Console tab of both windows.

---

`main.js` (main process)

```js
// Import required electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let launcherWindow;
let gameWindow;

function createLauncherWindow() {
    const launcherWindow = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    launcherWindow.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'launcher-window.html'))
        .then(() => { launcherWindow.show(); });

    return launcherWindow;
}

function createGameWindow() {
    const gameWindow = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 150,
        y: 150,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        parent: launcherWindow,
        // modal: true, // Optional
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true,
            // Let's use the same preload.js script
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    gameWindow.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'game-window.html'))
        .then(() => { gameWindow.show(); });

    return gameWindow;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    launcherWindow = createLauncherWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createLauncherWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.on('open-game-window', () => {
    gameWindow = createGameWindow();
})
```

---

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'game' methods
    'game', {
        openGameWindow: () => {
            ipcRenderer.send('open-game-window');
        },
        test: () => {
            console.log('test');
        }
    }
);
```

---

`launcher-window.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Launcher Window</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Launcher Window</h1>
        <hr>
        <input type="button" id="openGameWindow" value="Open Game Window">
    </body>

    <script>
        // On button click, open the game window
        document.getElementById('openGameWindow').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.game.openGameWindow();
        })

        // Testing
        window.game.test();
    </script>
</html>
```

---

`game-window.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Game Window</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Game Window</h1>
    </body>

    <script>
        // Testing
        window.game.test();
    </script>
</html>
```